# Getting site title in unknown format using Php Curl and Dom-Document

Tags: php, parsing, curl, domdocument, page-title

I want to get site title using site url with most of the site it is working but it is getting some not readable text with japennese and chinnese site.

Here is my function

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

**Use**

```
use--------
    $html = $this->file_get_contents_curl($url);
```

**Parsing**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I am getting this ouput "ã¢ã¡ã¼ãIDç»é² ã¡ã¼ã«ã®ç¢ºèªï½Ameba(ã¢ã¡ã¼ã)"

Site URL : https://user.ameba.jp/regist/registerIntro.do?campaignId=0053&frmid=3051

Please help me out suggest some way to get exact site title in any language.

//example

```
    /*  MEthod----------4 */
 function file_get_contents_curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

    $uurl="http://www.piaohua.com/html/xuannian/index.html";
    $html = file_get_contents_curl($uurl);

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
if(!empty($nodes->item(0)->nodeValue)){
$title = utf8_decode($nodes->item(0)->nodeValue);

}else{
    $title =$uurl;

}
echo $title;
```

Comment: Try UTF-8 when creating `DOMDocument`, like this `DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: `utf8_decode` might help

Comment: let me try utf8_decode

Comment: Can you give me example..@ djay

Comment: check with this url http://www.piaohua.com/html/lianxuju/2013/1108/27730.html

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal, What is your **expected output** ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran expected output is <title>疑犯追踪/嫌疑人第三季下载_迅雷下载_免费下载_飘花电影网</title> but i am getting ????/????????_????_????_?????

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this line on top of your PHP Code.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

### The code..

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl('http://www.piaohua.com/html/lianxuju/2013/1108/27730.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
echo $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: it is working fine but for url like https://user.ameba.jp/regist/registerIntro.do?campaignId=0053&frmid=3051 it is not working correct

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your script is using `utf-8` encoding by adding following line to the begining of the file

```
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

After doing so, remove `utf8_decode` function from your code. Everything should work fine without it

`[DOMDocument::loadHtml]`[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) function gets encoding from html page meta tag. So you could have problems if page do not excplicitly specifies its encoding.

Comment: Usage of what exactly? Also, you can check your environment locale using following line `echo setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0);`. If it's not utf8 then we will be closer to the issue

Comment: What about `mb_internal_encoding` function (call it in the beginning of your script)? Does it make the trick - or nothing changed? Remember to remove `utf8_decode` - you don't need it in this case